# Loop caused by AddListener

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've written the code below. However, sometimes this works, sometimes it loops and sometimes it doesn't work at all. What am I doing wrong? The extension is supposed to catch a message from a webpage, redirect and then push a message back to the content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender) {
    url = request.url;
    UName = request.username;
    PWord = request.password;
    chrome.tabs.update(sender.tab.id, {url: request.redirect});
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function doStuff(request) {   
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {message: "hello", username: UName, password: PWord}, function(response) {});
            chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(doStuff);
            return;
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Aha, there is some code redundancy i think.
Maybe, you can try like this:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender) {
  var url = request.redirect;
  var name = request.username;
  var pwd = request.password;
  var ti = sender.tab.id; // cache the tabId

  chrome.tabs.update(ti, {url: url});
  chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function doStuff(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (tabId === ti && changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
      chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(doStuff);
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {message: "hello", username: name, password: pwd}, function (callbackData) {
        // TODO something
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Good luck!